# css calc with center offset

Tags: html, css

[Here is what I am trying](http://jsfiddle.net/8p2okfgo/)

I have an element in the center that i want to stay in the center. 
Now i want an element to hug the left side of this element.

so in reality where i want the left most position of the left div would be right:calc(50%-200px-(lefts width));

my problem is doing right:50%; does something but right:calc(50% +100px) does not.

How can i make it so the div with the left class is always hugging the guy in the center?

```
<div class="left"> hug this center element </div>
<div class="middle"> this stays in the middle</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below works - adjust your HTML to this:

```
<div class="middle"> this stays in the middle
    <div class="left"> text here </div>
</div>
```

Change your CSS for `.left`

```
.left {
    position: relative;
    right: 60px; //adjust this to change left-right position of the .left div
}
```

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8p2okfgo/2/)

Comment: thats almost perfect so if i want it on the other side i would just do it to the right:205px ?

Comment: `left:205px;`...That was my original answer but then I read the question again and realized you wanted it on left.  For right side do `left:205px;`

Answer (score 6):

```
left: 50%; /* align center */
margin-left: -30px;  /* your element width / 2 when element = 60px */
```

Answer (score 5):

It is really very simple, but is dedicated to a single graphic or event. More importantly it also resolves the "resize" anomaly. So the code overhead is minimal. Using a graphic with a width of 300px, we need to state 50% within the method. Therefore:

```
     #imgone {
     left : calc (100% - 150px / 2);
     /* other code here*/;
     }
```

This most important rule is to ensure "white space" between + or - to avoid signed numbers. It is useful to adopt this convention  for both multiply and divide. All recognised value attributes (eg: px, pt, em, etc...) can be used. However 'auto' is treated differently by browsers and is excluded. Shame, with a bit of forward thinking "center-row:image' (sic) would have been an obvious method along with "center-col:image"(sic). Too easy, perhaps?

Comment: this is what user asked for.